# How to create more partitions od USB flash drive?

Tags: partitioning, usb, live-usb

I want to ask how to create more partitions od USB flash drive? and if is it possible under ubuntu. Will I be able to boot a live distribution from created partition?

which tool should I use, I was trying it with Gparted. But with no success.

Thank you.

Comment: Gparted can be used to partition an USB drive.

Do check if the USB flash drive is mounted before trying to partition the flash drive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gparted should be able to partition USB flash drives. Ubuntu disk utility should be able to do it also, you need to make sure it is not mounted first. In the disk utility there is an option to unmount the device. Failing that, fdisk should definitely work if you are happy with the command line.

I have installed Linux to USB drives before and they boot just fine. Remember to install grub to the USB drive.

Answer (score 0):

For a full install to USB I make the first partition FAT32 or NTFS so Windows can see the data, (Windows can only see the first partition on a flash drive). I then make the second partition /, the third /home and the fourth swap.

For a Persistent, (Live), install I make the first partition FAT32, as it is the only place a Live install will work, Windows data can be written to a folder on this partition. I make the second partition ext2 and name it casper-rw, it is where fresh installed programs go. The third partition is home-rw and is also ext2. this is like having a separate home partition.